# Get data from another form

Tags: c#

I have a listview in my Mainform and I need to get the value in the textbox and label in the other form name Add_Order?

```
Add_Order add = new Add_Order();
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = add.textBox3.Text;
item.SubItems.Add(add.label6.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(add.textBox2.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(add.textBox1.Text);
item.SubItems.Add(add.textBox3.Text);
mainform.listView2.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: Do you have the values in the field when you create the form ? Also i think you would need properties on the form which would expose the value of the respective fields which you could use on your `Mainform`

Comment: yes I have values on the field

Comment: Add_Order form is already opened?

Comment: not yet..
it will only open when I click one button..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would not expose the controls in your Add_Order Form. Your calling Form should not be aware of the internals of the Add_Order Form, only its public Methods and Properties. I would make a Public Method and use that to retrieve the information you need. something like this:

**Add_Order.cs**

```
public partial class Add_Order : Form
{
    public Add_Order()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public List<string> GetData()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add(textBox3.Text);
        list.Add(label6.Text);
        list.Add(textBox2.Text);
        list.Add(textBox1.Text);
        return list;
    }
}
```

**MainForm**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_Order add = new Add_Order();
    add.ShowDialog();

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    List<string> data = add.GetData();
    item.Text = data[0];
    item.SubItems.Add(data[1]);
    item.SubItems.Add(data[2]);
    item.SubItems.Add(data[3]);
    item.SubItems.Add(data[0]);
    listView2.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: how should my class look like??

Comment: @YOUn'Me In what way are you meaning, the example that I gave for your Add_Order Class should work. How do you want your workflow to work. In short in what order are you doing things.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data to other forms in different ways like creating public classes to maintain data common data between forms or you can pass data using form constructor like :

```
Add_Order frmAddOrder=new Add_Order(data1,data2);
frmAddOrder.show();
```

and in your Add_Order Constructor :

```
    public Add_Order (string data1,string data2)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
   //you can access data1 and data2 here ...

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I write a simple one for you:

Set element `Modifiers` to `true` in Add_Order form :

[image]

and get it in main form:

```
  public partial class main : Form
    {
        public main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Get_Frm2_Data();
        }
        private void Get_Frm2_Data()
        {
            Add_Order frm2 = new Add_Order();
            List<string> info= new List<string>;
            info.Add( frm2.textBox1.Text);
             .
             .
             .
        }
    }
```

**edit**

or make an structure:

**Add_Order.cs**

```
 public partial class Add_Order : Form
    {
        public Add_Order()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Info Get_Data()
        {
            return new Info() { _textBox3 = textBox3.Text,
                                _label6 = label6.Text,
                                _textBox2 = textBox2.Text,
                                _textBox1 = textBox1.Text,
            };
        }

    }
    struct Info
    {
        public string _textBox3;
        public string _label6;
        public string _textBox2;
        public string _textBox1;
    }
```

**Mainform.cs**

```
 public partial class main : Form
    {
        public main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Get_Frm2_Data();
        }
        private void Get_Frm2_Data()
        {
            Add_Order frm2 = new Add_Order();
            frm2.ShowDialog();
            Info lst_data= frm2.Get_Data();
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = lst._textBox3;
            item.SubItems.Add(lst._label6);
            item.SubItems.Add(lst._textBox2);
            item.SubItems.Add(lst._textBox1);
            mainform.listView2.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how should I used this oneV??